# Can the linear movement of a gyroscope be detected?

Tags: iphone, ios4, game-physics, gyroscope

Can i know through Gyroscope, if I've moved some distance?

To elaborate my question, can I be able to detect the device's motion if the user moves a couple of feet from the starting position?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear motion is detected using the accelerometer.  Rotation is detected using the gyroscope.

You can use the [`CMDeviceMotion`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009942) class to detect both types of movement.  You will have to integrate the value of `userAcceleration` over time to detect a change in position.

Check out the *What's New in Core Motion* video from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).  You will probably find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the post, will check them!